# Why is 者 (person) in 再者 (moreover; besides)?

Tags: meaning, word

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E5%86%8D%E8%80%85): 再者 (zài​zhě)  moreover / besides

The 者 is confusing me. If we break 再者 down into its characters, we get 再 ([again; then; further](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%86%8D)) and  者 ([that which; he who, she who; those who](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%80%85)). 再 makes sense. but I don't understand the role of 者? As a conjunction,  再者 is a functional morpheme, and is not limited to 者 (people).

In response to [Pedroski's question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/52718) "者 is not person who told you that?":

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/chinese_traditional-english/%E8%80%85) defines 者 as 人 and 物.

[Characters Indicating People: 师, 生, 员, 家, 者 and 人](https://mandarinfriend.wordpress.com/2016/02/20/characters-indicating-people-%E5%B8%88-%E7%94%9F-%E5%91%98-%E5%AE%B6-%E8%80%85-and-%E4%BA%BA/)

["that which; he who; those who; (after a verb or adjective) one who (is) ...; (after a noun) **person involved in** ..."](https://www.dong-chinese.com/dictionary/%E8%80%85)

Comment: The question as of now is very confusing. If you’re addressing Pedroski, please consider do so in their comment. Otherwise, please clarify how the additional links are pertinent to your question. Every dictionary you linked offers alternative definitions other than “person”, the Mandarin Friend link is only suggesting that 者 can mean person, *not* that it *only* means person.

Comment: @EEQ this person doesn't stop creating sockpuppet accounts and asking low-quality questions, and not following StackExchange etiquette in general. They refuse to learn how characters work in relation to the language (all of their questions are something like: **X dictionary says Y character means Z, how does Y mean Z in word W / how does Y's character components cause it to mean Z in word W**). They also (for some strange reason) persistently accept answers which they are not satisfied with; it's like they're only asking questions for drawing attention.

Comment: @dROOOze That is disheartening to hear. Thank you for the information.

Comment: @EEQ Pedroski wrote "者 is not person who told you that?". I listed those links to prove that 者 CAN mean person. I disagree with dROOze's rude comment. dROOze has confused me with someone else.

Comment: @Monica Very well. What confuses me is that, since you are able to provide the links, you are able to independently find out that 者 can also *not* mean person, so why ask this question? If you don’t find the other definitions adequate to explain its presence in 再者, you can say so and explain why in your question. Anyhow, seeing that you are not the same individual dROOze mentioned, I’m glad you are satisfied with the accepted answer. Good for you.

Comment: @EEQ "者 can also *not* mean person". This was not obvious to me from all these links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

再 : another

者 is not only used for person. It is just a word like "this" and "that", which can refer to anything.

So 再者 is another thing. It is usually used when there is something talked about, and now you want to talk about another elements. (An example: One advantage, 再者, another advantage)

Answer (score 0):

者 is not person who told you that?

Maybe it is used in the same sense as the English suffixes -er or -ist sometimes.

总的来说，**失利者**多于**得利者**。
Overall, there were more **losers** than **winners**.

I think wznmickey is exactly right!

再者：另外 apart from that
再者∶除了前面提列过的以外 furthermore
再者∶另外;此外 besides

再者，其他国家就是这么做的。
Besides, other countries are doing it.

他觉得开车太复杂，再者，他更喜欢走路。
He thinks driving is complicated, besides, he prefers walking.

Comment: Please see my edited updated question. [wznmickey](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/52712) wrote "者 is not only used for person.".

Comment: Aha, I see what you mean, but according to that logic, 手也是人 (meaning we are all 3 people, assuming you have 2 hands!)： 小提琴手 家也是人：小提琴家 You cannot, in English, just substitute person for -ist or -er: violinist, violin person, footballer, football person: you have changed the meaning. In "他们俩都是可爱、友好的人。" you cannot use 者 instead of 人。藏书者， ？藏书人？That's why I wouldn't think of 者 simply as "person". "person involved in something" or "person who is good at something" is better.

Answer (score -2):

`再者` this word is almost dead. it means `in another word`, or `in addtional`

这个词太土了，现在没人在口语中这么说话. 正式场合用的也很少。